# SP2013 Branding per team site

Tags: 2013, branding, design-manager

I have a question regarding the branding of non-publishing sites in SharePoint 2013.

I have a site, consisting of several different team sites, each site should have a unique brand attached to it. I understand the premise of creating composed looks, but from what I can find, you need to upload the master page files to each one of the collections individually for the master page to become available in the CL -> Site Layout Page drop down list.

This seems a bit tedious? If I have 50+ collections, do I need to manually copy those files across?

Tried searching for a Powershell command, but no luck. Is there a better way of applying different designs to collections in SharePoint without manual copying?